# How can I pass a matrix by reference in R

Tags: r

I am using a function recursively and the function has to update the matrix. I passed the function as an argument, but it seems matrix can only be passed as the pass by value, because the moment program comes out of the scope of function matrix doesn't hold updated values. Since, I have to do multiple updates in the matrix recursively, I have to pass it as a parameter. 
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: have you looked at R6 classes? you can do a lot of reference tricks with those.

Comment: @Shape I haven't, I'm pretty new to R. I will check it now.  Thanks